# Multiple runs of random generation in R

Tags: r, random, quantmod

I have three variables A, B, and C with a time-series of returns. I would to run a random sampling using `mvrnorm` from package `MASS`, to generate 30 values for A, B and C.

I would like to be able to repeat this operation 10000 times, each time generating 30 values for A, B, C.

I execute one iteration using:

```
sim.ret = mvrnorm(n = 30, mu = mu, Sigma = sigma)
```

How can I run this function 10,000 times? I then use the result of each iteration to do some computations.

Any help would be appreciated! Thanks.

Comment: Not a duplicate at all. My question is regarding  a random generation of a whole matrix, rather than a vector. I am looking for getting a result as a list of matrices. None of this is addressed in the links you posted.

Comment: Oups.. You are right, my bad!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use *replicate()*:

```
N = 10000
results = replicate(N, mvrnorm(n = 30, mu = mu, Sigma = sigma))
print(head(results, 10))
```

Comment: Thanks! Would `results` be a list?

Comment: On the simplest case the result is a matrix, where each column is a replicate.

Comment: Well, `mvrnorm(n = 30, mu = mu, Sigma = sigma))` is a matrix with 3 columns and 30 rows. But when I apply your suggestion, I do not get a bunch of matrices, I get a vector instead..

Comment: No, you probably getting a *list* or *array* back, where each element is a replicate (you can loop through lists using *lapply* for example).

Comment: weird.. I am not getting a list..

Comment: So it's an *array* object.

Comment: @Mariam try `simplify = TRUE` in `replicate`. You should get a `matrix`.

Comment: But this would mess up the structure of the result. I explicitely need to return a list of matrices, not an array.

Comment: that's almost the same structure...and arrays are faster i guess.

Comment: @SimonO101 I would get a matrix that way, but not structured as I want. So for each iteration, I need to get a matrix with nc = 3 and nr = 30. For 10,000 iterations, I expect a list with 10000 elements, each element is a matrix with nc = 3 and nr = 30.

Comment: @Mariam so `simplify = FALSE` then!!! Look at the documentation, that would have cleared it up instantly. The default for `simplify` is `"array"`.

Comment: @SimonO101 Perfect! I can accept your suggestion if you post it as an answer!! Thanks again

Comment: @Mariam if you want to `apply`some function to each element of your list you would use `lapply` to do this to an array, you can use `apply` on the appropriate dimension, in your case the 3rd dimension, so `apply( results , 3 , myfunction )` will work nicely. Add my suggestion as an edit to this answer. It doesn't warrant a whole new answer.

Comment: @Fernando +1 for `replicate()`. SimomO101 adjusted it nicely for my purpose!

Comment: Thanks. The R help can be 'hard' to read sometimes, but it's worth a try.